# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE (has extras) }

Tags: android-intent, bluetooth, google-tv

star smart google tv we try to make Bluetooth in `DISCOVERABLE` mode through the program we tried it in this way we check first device support the Bluetooth we get Bluetooth support it present now we make device(VIZIO co -star) in `DISCOVERABLE` mode.

```
  Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE );
  discoverableIntent.putExtra( BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300 );
  activity.startActivity( discoverableIntent );
```

But it throw error

> No Activity found to handle
>   `Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE (has extras) }`